# Where can I download the Antwerp and Paris Polyglot Bibles in PDF form?

Tags: bible-translation, resource-request

Throughout the 16th and 17th centuries, 4 important Polyglot Bibles were published.

The 1st one was the Complutensian Polyglot, issued in 1522.

The 2nd one was the Antwerp Polyglot issued 1569-1572.

The 3rd was the Paris Polyglot issued in 1645.

The 4th was the London Polyglot issued in 1657.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(book)

I tried searching for these to download as PDFs, but I was only able to find the Complutensian and London Polyglots.

Complutensian here - https://archive.org/details/complutensianpolyglot

London here - https://archive.org/details/walton_polyglot/

Is there any website where I can download the Antwerp and Paris Polyglot Bibles in PDF form?

Answer (score 1):

Having hunted for these myself recently, I don't know of anywhere to download all volumes of either. However, I did find a few places where one can access certain volumes from each:

In Google Books, I found this file which seemed to be primarily for the New Testament, including a short preface. You will note, however, that the text for much of the Old Testament seems to have been appended for some reason (the wisdom literature and the prophets only, I think) - https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_XOTP0rctIQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_book_other_versions_r&redir_esc=y

The first volume of the Paris Polyglot, including the text for the Pentateuch and seemingly the front matter for the entire collection, can be found here - https://repository.library.georgetown.edu/handle/10822/712682?show=full

Hope two years isn't too late to be useful. Enjoy!